# How do I set an attribute of a tkinter element to a variable in python 3.7?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use the code `w = Label ( master, width=, height=)` and set the width and height to this variable: `labelwidth = int(20)`.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Have you tried doing `width=labelwidth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter attributes are like any other parameters to a function/class, and can be set to variables.
You can simply write:

```py
w = Label(master, width=labelwidth, height=labelwidth)
```

Followed by placing the label wherever you want.